# Add index position Value of an array of array using Linq

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

We can do sum using `arr.Sum()` function. But if it is an array of arrays. How will we add all values.
suppose data is
Array/List is  `[[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[5,4,3]]`
how will you get s1 , sum of all first index value, s2 , sum of second index value and so on using LINQ.

Comment: So, for your specific example, you're hoping to return something like this? [[6], [12], [12]]?

Comment: @Je No, the output should be [ [9], [10], [11]]

Comment: Does each row have the same number of "columns"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to sum up *columns' values* with a help of *Linq*:

```
int[][] source = new int[][] {
  new int[] { 1, 2, 3},
  new int[] { 3, 4, 5},
  new int[] { 5, 4, 3},
};

int maxCol = source.Max(item => item.Length);

var colsSum = Enumerable
  .Range(0, maxCol)
  .Select(index => source.Sum(item => item.Length > index ? item[index] : 0))
  .ToArray(); // let's meaterialize into an array
```

Test:

```
Console.Write(string.Join(", ", colsSum));
```

Outcome:

```
 9, 10, 11
```

Summing up *lines' values* is easier:

```
// [6, 12, 12]
var linesSum = source
  .Select(item => item.Sum())
  .ToArray();
```

If you want *total* sum:

```
// 30
var total = source
  .Select(item => item.Sum())
  .Sum();
```

or

```
// 30
var total = source
  .SelectMany(item => item)
  .Sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use combination of `Aggregate` and `Zip`

```
var arrays = new[]
{
    new[] { 1, 2, 3 },
    new[] { 3, 4, 5 },
    new[] { 5, 4, 3 }
};

var result = 
    arrays.Aggregate(Enumerable.Repeat(0, 3), 
                    (total, array) => total.Zip(array, (sum, current) => sum + current));

// result = { 9, 10, 11 }
```

`Enumerable<T>.Zip` executes provided function with items of same index.

Comment: Will this work if one of the rows has a different numbers of entries to the other rows?

Comment: Yes it will, only `.Zip` function will calculate inner arrays until it reaches the end of one of them. So if smallest array have 2 items then it will calculate for two items. OP doesn't mention about this kind of restriction

Answer (score 0):

A possible LINQ based approach (which will handle variable number of columns in each row):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Test
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static IEnumerable<int> GetTotalsPerColumn(int[][] inputData)
        {
            var data = inputData.SelectMany(z =>
            {
                return z.Select((item, index) => new { item, index });
            })
                .GroupBy(z => z.index)
                .OrderBy(z => z.Key)
                .Select(y => y.Select(z => z.item).Sum()
            );

            return data;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var inputData = new[] {
                      new[] { 1, 2, 3, 5},
                      new[] { 3, 4, 5, 6},
                      new[] { 5, 4, 3},
                    };

            var values = GetTotalsPerColumn(inputData);

            foreach (var value in values)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(value);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

If you are happy to avoid LINQ, this is another approach you could consider.
`GetTotalsPerColumn` populates a `Dictionary` where the key is the column number, and the value is the sum.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Test
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var inputData = new[] {
                  new[] { 1, 2, 3, 5},
                  new[] { 3, 4, 5, 6},
                  new[] { 5, 4, 3},
                };

            var values = GetTotalsPerColumn(inputData);

            foreach (var value in values)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(value.Key + " - " + value.Value);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static Dictionary<int, int> GetTotalsPerColumn(int[][] inputData)
        {
            var values = new Dictionary<int, int>();

            foreach (var line in inputData)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
                {
                    int tempValue;

                    values.TryGetValue(i, out tempValue);
                    tempValue += line[i];
                    values[i] = tempValue;
                }
            }
            return values;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Question was about _using LINQ_ ;)

Comment: Good point @Fabio - thanks. I've added both a LINQ and non-LINQ version.

Comment: In line `return z.Select(item => new { item, index = index++ });` you don't need to calculate index by your self. `Select` method have overload with two arguments item and index. - `return z.Select((item, index) => new { item, index});`